# Ways of distributing 5 balls into 10 bins

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Just wanted to confirm that the number of ways to distribute 5 balls into 10 bins is ${5+9 \choose 9}$ so ${14 \choose 9}$. This is with replacement allowed!

Comment: search stars and bars (combinatorics) on wikipedia. It might be helpful here.

Comment: "Replacement allowed" doesn't really mean anything in this context.

Comment: Your answer is correct if the balls are indistinguishable and the bins are distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer ${14 \choose 9}$ is correct but you are not really replacing anything in this context. This is *not* like when you take out balls from an urn (with or without replacement).

Here you are distributing the balls between 10 containers so you can formulate it like this:
$$
*****|||||||||
$$

There are five stars (balls) and nine bars (container barriers). One possible arrangement is this:
$$
**|*||||||*||*
$$

where you have two balls in the first container, one ball in the second container, one in the eighth container and one in the tenth container.

So you need to distribute the 9 bars (or the 5 stars) between $9+5$ locations which can be done in ${14 \choose 9}$ ways as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Case $1$ is all balls go into one bin: there are $10 \choose 1$ possibilities here.

Case $2$ is all balls go into $2$ bins, with each bin containing at least one ball. First select two bins in $10 \choose 2$ different ways. After that, distribute 5 balls into the 2 bins which is ${5-1} \choose {2-1}$. So we have ${10 } \choose {2}$ $4 \choose 1$ possibilities here.

For case $3$, we have $10 \choose 3$ ${5-1} \choose {3-1}$

For case $4$, we have $10 \choose 4$ ${5-1} \choose {4-1}$

For case $5$, we have $10 \choose 5$ ${5-1} \choose {5-1}$

The final answer is $${10 \choose 1}  + {10 \choose 2} {4 \choose 1} + {10 \choose 3} {4 \choose 2} + {10 \choose 4} {4 \choose 3} + {10 \choose 5}= 2002$$

Comment: Assumption: balls are indistinguishable/identical and bins are distinguishable/distinct as you have already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The case you're working with seems to be that of **identical** balls and **distinct** bins. The number of ways of doing this is the same as (can you see why?) the number of non-negative integral solutions of $$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{10}  = 5$$

This has $\binom{14}{9}$ solutions. As pointed out by @saulspatz, "replacement" allowed or not, doesn't mean anything in this context.

Comment: You should explain why the equation has $\binom{14}{9}$ solutions.